# Issue after waking from sleep mode

Tags: suspend

This happens after my laptop goes automatically or manually in sleep mode and then when I wake it up:

[image]

This seems a graphics problem? I`m running nvidoa 840m on my HP Pavilion 15.

Anyway to resolve this?